# Inject a service into all component of module

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a module composed with a Component and a bunch of sub component. There is also a service dedicated to this module.

I am not sure to understand the injection mecanism for my needs. 
What's i want to do is to inject the Service into all sub component.

When i inject Service with a provider into components it's ok but i wanted to set provider on module level.

**Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ChangeUserComponent } from './change-user.component';
import { ChangeUserSidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { ChangeUserUserListComponent } from './user-list/user-list.component';

import { ChangeUserService } from './change-user.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChangeUserComponent,
        ChangeUserUserListComponent,
        ChangeUserSidebarComponent
    ], 
    providers      : [
        ChangeUserService // <-- when i set that it's not working
    ],
    exports     : [
        ChangeUserComponent
    ]
})

export class ChangeUserModule
{
}
```

**Sub component**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChangeUserService } from '../change-user.service';

@Component({
    selector   : 'change-user-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
    //providers:  [ ChangeUserService ] // <-- with that the service is correctly injected
})
export class ChangeUserSidebarComponent
{

  public activeNode: any;

    constructor(
      private _changeUserService: ChangeUserService
    )
    {
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ChangeUserService 
{
    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
    ){}
}
```

Service is correctly injected when i set Provider on the component level but i wanted to set it on module level.

Edit : When i set keyword provider on Component level : everything is ok

When is set keyword providers on module level :

> *Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ChangeUserSidebarComponent -> ChangeUserService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ChangeUserSidebarComponent -> ChangeUserService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeUserService!*

Is there a way to do that ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is there a problem? Your module snippet is correct, that is how you register a singleton provider over the whole app. You'll have to show us a specific error if you're getting one.

Comment: The injection is done in the constructor, not in the providers section. It should work as you want. What's the error ?

Comment: Yes, when i set provider on Module Level,  compiler yell, i have edited the question .I don't want to register it for the whole app (injectable provided in root ?) but just for the module and all Component imported by this module (in the example ChangeUserComponent,  ChangeUserUserListComponent &       ChangeUserSidebarComponent). The goals is to register service only on module level for all the imported component ant not to set keyword providers into each @Component block of imported components.

Comment: You can't scope a provider to a module unless it is a lazily loaded module. Anything can inject a provider if it has access to the type.

Comment: Again, there's nothing wrong with your code and it shouldn't produce that error, can you create a minimal recreation of the problem on [stackblitz?](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Wow, you right it's working in minimalistic example : https://angular-armrkd.stackblitz.io

Comment: is it because of this kind of thing that i have into my routing and i am using Lazy loading without understanding it ? :  loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)

Comment: That snippet does produce a lazy loaded module, yes, but I still see no problem with your example. If a module provides a service and a component, then the component uses that service then there is no problem, lazy loaded or not. However you cannot use a lazy loaded module's service from outside that module (except in submodules) because you cannot access the type. As soon as you reference the type the lazy loading is broken.

Comment: Many thank for your explanations. That was how i understood the concepts and in-facto i don't see too why service providing isn't working in my code (as you can see, the reproduction of what i want to do, and according to your advices, is working in Stackbitz....). I will investiguate and share the answer if i find it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is interesting.

On the component level you can have a service injected (so you can inject the service directly in each sub component, but that would not only be troublesome, but also every component will have its new instance of the service)

But if you lock me down a dungeon and say to do it by any means here is what I will do. I would lazy load that module.

Explanation:

1. We have two modules (AppModule and LazyModule) that provide the same service.
2. As our second module is lazy , Angular doesn’t know about its existence. .This means that any service listed in the providers array of our LazyModule isn’t available because the root injector doesn’t know about LazyModule ... yet. When we activate the route, lazy module will be loaded and new injector created. Imagine a tree of injectors, on top there is the root injector and for each lazy module, new child injector will be created.
3. All services from root injector will be added to child injector. If root injector and child injector provide the same service, Angular prefers service instances from child injector. So every lazy component gets the local instance of the service, not the instance in the root application injector.
4. So the Lazy will work with its own another reference, and the rest of the app will have it

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't lock anyone in a dungeon to do that ;-) !

Finally i've decided to follow the first solution and put the service Injectable for Root. Don't want to do complex things to avoid something that would/should never happened (i-e : use the service into another component than the one devoted to this service).

Initially what i really wanted to do was to scope the service to it's module only, and provide it to the children components of the module.

Put the service for Root allow me to share the service and i will be assuming that the service should not be used by other parts of the app.

Anyway i still not know why set providers fir the service into the module isn't working in my context.